# Need to find anything but FF

Tags: regex

I need a regex pattern, that will search the file for lines where something else then hex-FF (256) is present. Thank you :)

Comment: FF(hex) is 255(dec) not 256, but has nothing to do with the problem :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?!FF*$).+
```

After a quick test round seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for grep, use:

`grep -v 'FF' <file>`

Comment: Coding .net & without Cygwin =(

Answer (score 0):

We can use [negative lookahead](http://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this:

```
^((?!FF).)*$
```

[Test it here](http://www.rubular.com/r/bzAZHaVIWj)